# Compile Go file in Windows?

Tags: compiler-construction, go

I am trying to learn Go and have installed [Go MinGW](http://code.google.com/p/gomingw/downloads/list) but I cannot find out how to actually compile a .go file ANYWHERE.  This is the program linked directly from the Go wiki for Windows Support, but all the tutorials talk about using 6g and gccgo etc. to compile and none of those work from my windows machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm dumb, the file linked is 32 bit and I was using "6g" to compile because my system is 64 bit.  "8g" works to compile.
"8g myfile.go"
"8l myfile.8"
"myfile.out"
Works to get it running.

Comment: I download Go from the same website as you. However, I am facing problem with compiling it. I put my "myfile.go" in src folder and after going to src folder I run the command "8g myfile.go" in command prompt. But. it showing error "open myfile.go nosuch file or directory". Can you kindly help me by specifying the complete steps of compiling. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry Arpssss, I only played around with Go for about a week.  I can't help you.